# Sending html emails on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, email-client, kindle-fire

In our app we send emails with some html in them. This works fine on every "normal" Android device but when I send these emails from a Kindle Fire it seems that by the time the email reaches the recipient the mime encoding has been changed from text/html to text/plain.

When the email is first created in the email client on the Kindle you can see that the href has been set because the linked text is in blue instead of the normal black.

I've tried the K-9 email client for the Fire to see if this makes any difference but there is no change. Here's the example code from our share app via email (I use the Manufacturer of the device to determine whether to use Google Play or Amazon app market links):

```
  Shareable shareable = new ShareableApp(Build.MANUFACTURER);

  final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  emailIntent.setType("text/html");
  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.share_app_email_subject));
  emailIntent.putExtra(
          android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
          Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.share_email_content, "<a href=\"" + NetworkQuery.HTTP + shareable.getShareHost() + "/" + shareable.getSharePath() + "\">" + shareable.getShareTitle() + "<//a>") + "<br><br>"
              + this.getString(R.string.share_email_description)));
  final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
  final List<ResolveInfo> emailers = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);
  if (emailers.size() > 0) {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
  } else {
     displayMessage(R.string.dialog_message_no_email_client);
  }
```

Is there any way to get an html email sent correctly from a Kindle Fire?

### Edit

> If I send an HTML email to a Kindle Fire I can then send it somewhere else and the Mime encoding is maintained. It just seems to be that the setType("text/html") isn't persisted when the email is actually created on the Kindle.